# Dict values incrementation in succession validation

Tags: python

I have a following task:

There is a dict like:

```
{1: datetime.date(2020, 7, 2), 2: datetime.date(2020, 7, 2), 11: datetime.date(2021, 7, 2)}
```

and it should follow one rule:

datetime object in value  of each following element in dict should be >= than previous  element ‘s value in dict after dict is sorted by keys. Result should be bool of whether this rule is violated or not.

Examples:

correct (each following date gte than previous one)

```
{1: datetime.date(2020, 7, 2),  2: datetime.date(2020, 7, 2), 11: datetime.date(2021, 7, 2)}
```

incorrect (2017 < than 2020 in previous element)

```
{1:  datetime.date(2020, 7, 2),  2: datetime.date(2020, 7, 2),  11:  datetime.date(2017, 7, 2)}
```

What I do to validate proper order:

```
import more_itertools
# sort dict by keys
sorted_by_keys_numbers = dict(sorted(original_dict.items()))
# check if rule is violated or not
are_dates_sorted = more_itertools.is_sorted(sorted_by_keys_numbers .values()) 
# returns True or False
```

But it heavily function based and non-pythonic

Is it any alternative, that are:

1. Pythonic

2)Non massive with multiple levels of nested FOR, IF, etc

Thank you

P>S Python 3.8, so all element are mantain order

Comment: "But it heavily function based and non-pythonic" - what makes you say it's non-pythonic? The function calls? Calling functions is completely normal; please don't try to avoid calling functions.

Comment: It certainly looks pythonic to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this with an expression generator and a zip on two list built from dictionary value

```py
from datetime import datetime
data = {1: datetime(2020, 7, 2),
        2: datetime(2020, 7, 2),
        11: datetime(2021, 7, 4)}
res = all(i <= j for i, j in zip(list(data.values()), list(data.values())[1:]))
```